# how do I make the spinner in my Progressdialog spin?

Tags: android, progressdialog

I've implemented the `progressDialog` but it's not spinning when my activity starts and when it does work or fetches info from the internet. I've tried many solutions here on Stackoverflow and other places but it still doesn't spin - the `progressDialog` pops up ok but wheel not spinning. Many suggestions are in agreement on using `AsyncTask`, starting a new thread/runnable instead of the UI thread, but still no luck. I'd be grateful for any solutions.

With help from posts on Stackoverflow I tried this in the `OnPreExecute` of my `AsyncTask`...but now the `progressDialog` doesn't even show up!:

```
 protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(NewContact.this);
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Showing progress dialog 
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            pDialog.show();
        }
    });
}
```

The code I had been using, which shows the `progressDialog` but it's not spinning, is :

```
 protected void onPreExecute() {
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(NewContact.this);
    // Showing progress dialog before making http request
    pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    pDialog.show();
    super.onPreExecute();
}
```

Here's the complete code structure for the activity:

```
public class NewContact extends AppCompatActivity implements android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_contact);
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, NewContact_URL,
                        new Response.Listener<String>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(String response) {

                            }
                        },
                        new Response.ErrorListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                            }

                        }) {

                    protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        return params;
                    }


                };

            }



    // Load data in background
    class LoadContact extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(NewContact.this);

            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {


                    // Showing progress dialog
                    pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
                    pDialog.show();
                }
        });

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            hidePDialog();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        LoadContact loadContact = new LoadContact();
        loadContact.execute();
    }

public void hidePDialog() {
    if (pDialog != null) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
        pDialog = null;
    }
}
}
```

In my `res/values/styles.xml` I have:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

I don't remember ever going into the `styles.xml` and setting those values. My App works fine (apart from spinner) but the `=Theme...` parts of the `styles.xml`  are all in red and when I put the mouse over them I get the message:

```
Cannot resolve symbol 'Theme.AppCompat'
Cannot resolve symbol 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'  
Cannot resolve symbol 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'
```

Could this be related to my problem?

Comment: Your previous method of showing progress dialog was correct. I think Progress Dialog is not spinning because of some heavy work done by StringRequest on the main UI thread and i am not able to understand what does this StringRequest does ?

Comment: share your theme for that activity

Comment: Downvoter:please comment on reason why. Thought about the question and tried solving and don't know how, that's why I posted. Away from machine at the moment, will post theme shortly, thanks. All the string request does is get some small text from the server.

Comment: @NileshRathod added information about themes in my question

Comment: @CHarris where is your primarycolor & primarydarkcolor in theme

Comment: @NileshRathod Where would I find info about that? In my Manifest.xml all I have in relation to the activity is  `<activity android:name="com.example.chris.tutorialspoint.NewContact"`

Comment: @CHarris may its not issue with code i think its theme problem i have also same problem using Progress dialog just check in your styles.xml]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157707/discussion-between-nilesh-rathod-and-charris).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to wrap the stuff in `onPreExecute` in a new thread, you're not doing anything that is blocking the UI there. You also seem to have an extra closing bracket before you return null. I changed it to look like this:

```
 // Load data in background
class LoadContact extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        // Showing progress dialog
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        hidePDialog();
    }
}
```

After making these changes it is working fine for me. One thing to check is that you don't have animations turned off in Developer Options on the device. If they are turned off (like they need to be for Espresso testing) then the spinner will not show.

Comment: I think my problem is related to themes, still working on it. Interesting about Developer Options though.